# Fetching data from URL in Julia behind proxy, using Requests get

Tags: julia

Attempting to fetch data from URL using the Requests package in Julia throws a "Connection refused" error, which is not a surprise as I have attempted to do this behind a corporate proxy. Is there a way to overcome this, say by setting some http_proxy variable in my Julia script?
The http_proxy environment varable is set.

Comment: From within your script/repl session is `ENV["http_proxy"]` (n.b. `http_proxy` should be lower case) set to the expected value? Note to connect to https urls you need to set `https_proxy`.