# How to make HTTP request in Julia behind proxy?

Tags: http, proxy, request, julia

Julia noob, and just trying a few simple exercises.

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
using HTTP
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/googl"
r = HTTP.request("GET", url)
```

and getting a timeout error.

A few comments:

- I am behind a corporate proxy.  I have set http_proxy and https_proxy (and their capitalized equivalents), and I have made the .gitconfig file aware of these settings.
- No problems with the equivalent code using Python urllib2.
- Tried http version of the URL--no luck.
- Tried POST instead of GET--still no luck.
- Verbose option did not reveal any extra info.

This is the top of the stack trace:

> ERROR: LoadError: IOError: connect: connection timed out (ETIMEDOUT)
>   Stacktrace:
>    [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647471/fetching-data-from-url-in-julia-behind-proxy-using-requests-get) try_yieldto(::typeof(Base.ensure_rescheduled), ::Base.RefValue{Task}) at ./event.jl:196
>    [2] wait() at ./event.jl:255
>    [3] wait(::Condition) at ./event.jl:46
>    [4] stream_wait(::Sockets.TCPSocket, ::Condition) at ./stream.jl:47
>    [5] wait_connected(::Sockets.TCPSocket) at ./stream.jl:263
>    [6] connect at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Sockets/src/Sockets.
>   jl:444 [inlined]
>    [7] connect(::Sockets.IPv4, ::UInt64) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib
>   /v1.0/Sockets/src/Sockets.jl:428
>    [8] #getconnection#14(::Bool, ::Int64, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Symbol,Union{Nothing, Bool},Tuple{Symbol,Sy
>   mbol},NamedTuple{(:require_ssl_verification, :iofunction),Tuple{Bool,Nothing}}}, ::Function, ::Type{Socket
>   s.TCPSocket}, ::SubString{String}, ::String) at /home/T2213331/.julia/packages/HTTP/nUK4f/src/ConnectionPo
>   ol.jl:548

Per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33647471/fetching-data-from-url-in-julia-behind-proxy-using-requests-get) I have confirmed that `ENV["http_proxy"]` and `ENV["https_proxy"]` are both correctly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work

```
HTTP.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/googl", proxy="http://123.123.123.123:8888")
```

Of course you need to provide a correct proxy IP and port.

Comment: Is it possible to use a sock5 proxy? I tried `proxy="socks5://127.0.0.1:1080"` but it says `IOError(EOFError() during request(socks5://127.0.0.1:1080))` (I have a working socks5 proxy runing there).

Comment: Looking at the HTTP.jl source code I have a filling that only the http  proxy is supported.You can either use PyCall with Python `urllib2` or configure Tinyproxy with a http proxy having an upstream setting to Socks5 (I have not tested that though)

Comment: This got me I think 90% of the way there.  It does seem that only HTTP and not HTTPS is supported, which is fine because we have both (but not SOCKS).  Now I'm getting an authentication error:

ERROR: HTTP.ExceptionRequest.StatusError(407, HTTP.Messages.Response:

Comment: The http_proxy variable has the form http://username:password@proxy.abc.com:8080

I don't see any additional HTTP.request options to take my authentication info, so kinda stuck at this point.  I don't need this for any particular reason, just playing around, but I figured I'd just document what I'm seeing for posterity.

Comment: Found the final piece here: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717932/julia-http-get-api-key-authorization

`auth = "Basic " * Base64.base64encode(user * ":" * password)`
`proxy = "http://proxy.abc.com:8080"`
`r = HTTP.get("http://www.google.com", proxy=proxy, headers = ["Proxy-Authorization" => auth])`

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!